# Convex Layers of a Planar Set - Recursion Run time

Tags: geometry, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to analyze the run time of an algorithm that returns a set of convex hulls, in layers, on a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have a subroutine of finding the convex hull, which runs on the order of $O(n\log h)$. $n$ represents the number of input points and $h$ is the number of edges on the convex hull. The idea is that you compute the convex hull, and then recursively call it on the interior points. How should I think about the run time when my points are being reduced by some $3 \leq h_i \leq n$ at every recursive step? 
I feel it looks something like this:

$n\log h_0 + (n-h_0)\log h_1 + (n-h_0-h_1)\log h_2 + \cdots + (n - \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}h_i)\log h_m + c$

But I'm unsure how to view it from big O notation or how to get it started.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Which part is not making sense?

Comment: Why would you call the routine recursively if you already have computed the hull?

Comment: Because I'm wanting convex layers. So if you have a set of points, you compute what the convex hull is in n log h time. Remove those h points, and then find the next convex hull. It's different than just computing the convex hull.

Comment: Well, it seems to me your quantity is less than $O(n^2log(h_{max})$ where $h_{max}$ is the max of the $h_i$'s, for obvious reasons... Is that helpful or is it too crude?

Comment: Sort of, I feel like there's a connection between the h_i's and n (since n limits h). But I totally agree that it is lower than n^2log(Max h).